# Resulting all the indices while trying to get only those indices which are associated with specific alias

Tags: elasticsearch

I have recently upgraded application from Elastic search 5.3.1 to 6.0.

My requirement was to get all the indices which were associated with specific alias.

I used below mentioned snippet to fetch all indices associated with specific alias . This snippet is working fine in 5.3.1 and giving only those indices which are associated with that specific alias.

```
GetAliasesResponse r = client.admin().indices().getAliases(new 
GetAliasesRequest("givenalias")).actionGet();
```

But after ES 6.0 , the same snippet giving all the indices which are created in system .

Ideally it should only return those indices which are associated with given alias .Not others. This was working in Elastic search 5.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It is an [intended breaking change](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/5b2ab96364335539affe99151546552423700f6e) in the [Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/6.0/java-api.html) of Elasticsearch (though it is not explicitly mentioned in the ["Breaking changes in 6.0 » Java API changes"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking_60_java_changes.html) page).

The following is the story of discovering this fact. (Note: the original answer was heavily edited, hence comments might be out of date.)

### Breaking changes in the REST API in 6.0

First I noticed that this part of the REST API changed in Elasticsearch 6.0. There are two reported *breaking* changes concerning aliases:

- [`GET /_aliases,_mappings`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking_60_rest_changes.html#_indices_information_apis) syntax was removed in favor of `GET /_aliases`/`GET /_mappings`
- [Indices aliases api resolves indices expressions only against indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_60_indices_changes.html#_indices_aliases_api_resolves_indices_expressions_only_against_indices)

Though there isn't mentioned anything concerning OP's case.

From what I have seen doing queries, this query works in Elasticsearch 5:

```
GET /alias1/_aliases
```

And does not work in Elasticsearch 6, giving the following error:

```
{
  "error": "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/alias1/_aliases] and method [GET], allowed: [PUT]",
  "status": 405
}
```

Interestingly, `GET /alias1/_alias` works in both versions and returns same result.

Moreover, I didn't manage to find an example of `GET /alias1/_aliases` in the documentation of nor [5.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-aliases.html), neither [6.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/indices-aliases.html#alias-retrieving).

### Reproducing the bug

After having realised that OP is actually using the Java API, I managed to reproduce the exact same behavior.

The following code:

```
GetAliasesResponse alias1 = client.admin().indices()
    .getAliases(new GetAliasesRequest("alias1")).actionGet();
```

In ES 5 produces this in the IntelliJ debugger:

[image: GetAliasesResponse in ES 5]

And for ES 6 I've got the following:

[image: GetAliasesResponse in ES 6]

As you can see, there are extra keys in the second output, which have empty values.

### Diving into the source code

Quick search over the elasticsearch codebase gave me the final explanation. In ES 5 there was a test `testIndicesGetAliases` which was checking that list of indices returned for a test alias has exactly one element ([IndexAliasesIT.java#L554](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/5.3/core/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/aliases/IndexAliasesIT.java#L554)):

```
    logger.info("--> getting alias1");
    GetAliasesResponse getResponse = admin().indices().prepareGetAliases("alias1").get();
    assertThat(getResponse, notNullValue());
    assertThat(getResponse.getAliases().size(), equalTo(1));
```

And in 6.0 it checks that the size is 5! ([IndexAliasesIT.java#L573](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.0/core/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/aliases/IndexAliasesIT.java#L573))

```
    logger.info("--> getting alias1");
    GetAliasesResponse getResponse = admin().indices().prepareGetAliases("alias1").get();
    assertThat(getResponse, notNullValue());
    assertThat(getResponse.getAliases().size(), equalTo(5));
```

This change was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/5b2ab96364335539affe99151546552423700f6e), which is related to these issues:

- [Remove comma-separated feature parsing for GetIndicesAction #24723](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/24723)
- [_alias API no longer accepts index wildcards #25090](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25090)

This is actually interesting, because one of the reported REST API breaking changes that we have see above also broke compatibility of some Java API calls.

### What you can do

In short term, you need just to filter out those keys with empty values.

In longer term I think it makes sense to migrate to [Java High Level REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.0/java-rest-high.html#java-rest-high) since Elastic plan to [deprecate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/6.0/java-api.html) the TransportClient in version 7.0:

> We plan on deprecating the TransportClient in Elasticsearch 7.0 and
>   removing it completely in 8.0. Instead, you should be using the Java
>   High Level REST Client, which executes HTTP requests rather than
>   serialized Java requests.

In general, Elasticsearch breaks compatibility quite often, so it's better to stay away from the dark corners of it like Java API.

Thanks for reading.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am agree with all points that you have mentioned. Queries are also correct. But I facing issue with this api. It returns a map which contains the indices as key and alias as values. When i was on ES5.3.1 it only returns the map in which key (indices ) belongs to given alias ("givenalias")  but after 6.0 it returns all the indices in keys  but interesting  thing is  values (AliasMetaData) are only available  to  those indices which are actually associated . Other key indices null or empty array. I am just trying to find why this api giving all indices. Its an incorrect  behaviour of api.

Comment: Client library  is also in sync and updated. It looks me a bug in client library.  Because  http query returns  expected  result but not the same with api.

Comment: @antitech which one is the client library?

Comment: Elastic search client 6.0.0

Comment: @antitech Ok now I got it, I was thinking that you are using some kind of a wrapper client around REST, but actually you are using native Java client ([this one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html)). I never used it so didn't recognize. I updated the answer with recent findings.

Comment: Thank you @Nikolay Vasiliev . Great help for me. Menawhile i mentioned this issue on elastic forum too.

Comment: @antitech great!